# AngularJS - ng-change fired with the controller initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have something like this in my template:

```
<input name="searchText" placeholder="Search" data-type="search" 
       ng-model="searchText" 
       ng-change="searchRecords()" 
       ng-keyup="onKeyUp()">
```

When I get to that template, `searchRecords()` function is called (ng-change is fired). I want `searchRecords()` to be called only when I start typing (change `searchText` will fire `ng-change`). Right now it is fired with the controller initialization.

I tried to set `searchText` to `null`, `''` in the controller but it was the same.

Is this behavior by design or I am missing something?

**EDIT:**

I realized that this code fires my `searchRecords()`:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['daysBefore', 'daysAhead'], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) { ... }
```

**EDIT:**

I deleted the `ng-change` and added this:

```
$scope.$watch('searchText', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.searchRecords();
            });
```

Without any change of the `$scope.searchText` this code is executing on controller initialization.

Comment: What does the controller look like?

Comment: You may be calling searchRecords() in your controller

Comment: initialize $scope.searchText=""; in controller then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a thread about that in a google group for angular - 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/uXldMqsQvRw

> The watch fires automatically (and asynchronously via $evalAsync) upon registration, this is initialize the watcher and let your code know what the initial value is.
>
> If this is undesirable then you can put this check into your save method:
>
> function save(newVal, oldVal) {
>         if (newVal === oldVal) return;
>         // do stuff here
>       }

So yeah, I wanted to get away from such code, but obviously I can't

Answer (score 5):

You may use ng-init to set a flag, for example:" ng-init='initializing=true' ", and check within the ng-change function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. Please have a look at [tips on how to make your answer great](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). When unsure, it is always advisable to use the comments instead of posting low quality answers - comments are great when you want to suggest a quick "check" or confirm your "suspicion", or perhaps share a link to related resources.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ng-change you can create the watcher for ng-model of that input.

```js
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.searchText;
}, function(n, o) {
  if(n != o){
    $scope.searchRecords();
  }  
}, true);
```

```html
<input ng-model="searchText">
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ng-model, then it is normal to have a ng-change event.
You should do a $watch of the $scope.searchText var instead.

Comment: See my EDIT, so why this `watch` is called without change on those fields?

Comment: your ng-model fires a change